# Why it is impossible to delete an old Windows system folder?

Tags: windows-8-upgrade

When I upgraded my os I choosed to custom install the upgrade and it makes a backup of my old windows. During the custom install I needed to restart the custom install for some strange reason but in the end I get it working. My problem is to delete the old windows system folders especially windows.old.001 to windows.old.00X in my system drive and also the program files folder etc.pp. It gives me the error message not enough rights to delete the folder but I already changed the owner of the folder to no avail?

Comment: Did you change the owner **and** gave the owner rights to delete? (probably yes since you already changed ownership, but just making sure).

Answer (score 2):

Run Disk Cleanup.  Check off "Old Windows Installations."  When Disk Cleanup finishes, all Windows.old.XXX folders should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look to see if they are read only?  Go to explorer and right-click on the folder and look for the tag.  Uncheck the box under read only and you should be golden.  If that does not work for some reason you could always use a linux live disk (like from Ubuntu) and mount the hard disk in there to do it.